# Duplicated content from main page and index page

Tags: html, css

I hope I can make my question very clear but if I can't please be forgivable.

We have created a website and it called : `www.website.com` and with this website, it read the index.html file and therefore there will be this website: `www.website.com/index.html`.
Obviously, these two will be the same with same content and everything.

My question here is how can I separate them. As in, when we audit the site, it keeps coming back as these two website are having duplicated content, duplicated title, and so on.

I tried to find an answer but I couldn't understand it myself so I couldn't find any question or answer related so if anyone could help that's be great.

Many thanks

Comment: it's a bit unclear, your goal is to dismiss the /index site when doing SEO?

Comment: See [Canonical Link Element](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_link_element) on Wikipedia. This informs search engines what the real URL of the current article is and that it should ignore the duplicate content of the current URL.

Comment: How do you "audit the site"? Maybe there is some links that leads to `www.website.com` and others that leads to `www.website.com/index.html`? Maybe you need canonical URLs added to page? https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/crawling/consolidate-duplicate-urls

Comment: I use SEM rush and use their site audit features, it's mentioned our website.com and website.com/index has same content

Comment: I think my goals is to set the 2 pages into one but how can I do it?

Answer (score 2):

I just want to let you know I fixed the problems, it's to add this code to .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ / [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/index\.html$ /$1/ [R=301,L]
```